# Mysterious Namespace dependency not required: ‘rlang’

Tags: r

This function runs correctly on its own.  When executed in R Studio, it opens the `View` function and the window is labeled correctly as `mtcars` (not `df`):

```
#' Print a data frame appropriate to output type
#'
#' @param df the data frame to be printed
#'
#' @return either kable (in PDF) or datatable (in HTML) output
#' @importFrom DT datatable
#' @importFrom knitr kable
#' @importFrom utils View
#' @importFrom rlang enexprs
#' @export
#'
#' @examples # sp_print_df(df)
sp_print_df <- function(df){
  df_name <- enexprs(df)
  if (knitr::is_latex_output()) {
    knitr::kable(df)(df)
  }
  else if (knitr::is_html_output()) {
    DT::datatable(df)
  }
  else {
    View(df, title = as.character(df_name[[1]]))
    }
  }
library(rlang)
sp_print_df(mtcars)
```

I'm having some problems including this function in a package (https://github.com/smithjd/sqlpetr).

Various permutations of  `@importFrom` in the `.R` file and the `rlang (>= 0.3.0.1),` in the package `DESCRIPTION` file (either as `Imports:` or as `Suggests` all result in the same error message when I do `devtools::check()` in R Studio:

```
❯ checking package dependencies ... ERROR
  Namespace dependency not required: ‘rlang’

  See section ‘The DESCRIPTION file’ in the ‘Writing R Extensions’
  manual.

1 error ✖ | 0 warnings ✔ | 0 notes ✔
Error: R CMD check found ERRORs
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.
```

The `roxygen` package is appropriately generating the NAMESPACE file, as far as I can tell (this is a snippet):

```
importFrom(purrr,map_chr)
importFrom(rlang,enexprs)
importFrom(stringr,str_detect)
importFrom(tibble,as_tibble)
```

What am I missing about "imports from"?  Or is this a `View` or `rlang` problem?

Comment: Have you updated rlang in a while? `update.packages('rlang')`. I had a similar problem recently and updating it cleared the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the devtools::check() error was a ghost somewhere in a sqlpetr.Rcheck folder that it creates next door to the package directory.  Once that error message had been issued it would not go away, even after I corrected the problem.  Once I deleted that directory, the error message disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

You have to include the **rlang** package in the **Imports** section (or **Depends**, but if I recall correctly the advised section is **Imports**) of your **DESCRIPTION** file.

The "**importFrom rlang enexprs**" in the function is correct, unfortunately - other than the NAMESPACE file - the DESCRIPTION file is not updated automatically so you have to include all packages that you listed with **importFrom** in your **Description** file manually.

Comment: Thanks!  I believe I've got the NAMESPACE and DESCRIPTION files synched with how the function is written and I still get the error message when running `devtools::check()`.  As if `rlang` is imported some way that I can't see.